# Find and replace using wildcards without changing the wildcard in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, html, notepad

I am trying to replace the following pattern

```
A<marker>
B<marker>
C<marker>
```

etc. with

```
<marker>A
<marker>B
<marker>C
```

A,B,C etc. stand for single, non-alphanumeric characters. There's a large list, so replacing each individually is impossible.

In short, I am trying to find the pattern X<marker> and replace it with <marker>X, but without replacing the X with a custom character.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the entries and find/replace using regex option.

Find: `(.)(.*)`
Replace: `\2\1`

[image]

---

Please mark this solution as an answer if it solves your problem. Otherwise, please leave comments as to why it falls short. Thank you.

Comment: I have other text surrounding the markers, so unfortunately this approach does not work.

Comment: then you need to provide us sufficient details to solve the problem.